# Example or tutorial of sending an email in iPhone from another application

Tags: iphone, email

I am developing an iPhone application .

In this app If the user likes to share the information that is currently shown I want to provide a button named "Share" .

On tapping "Share" the user will be provided with all the contacts from the address book .

After that on tapping one of the user the related details should be embedded in the email and the mail should be sent to the relevant person .

Is the any tutorial or example then suggest me ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a class named MFMailComposeViewControler. take a look at apple's MailComposer example. [link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/MailComposer.zip)

Comment: jtbandes is right as I have googled for this topic and got the class name but want a example so I can easily learn it .

Comment: I've added the link to zip with sample. MFMailComposeViewController is a very simple class. and this link you can find in documentation provided with xcode. so i didn't think that it is necessary to post it.

Answer (score 0):

your app here works fine! thanks a lot for this link http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/MailComposer.zip