# How to add attchment and signature in email through programming in iPhone App/

Tags: iphone, html, ios, email

How can I add video/image/audio as an attachment programmatically in the email in iPhone app iPhone and how can I add Signature? I think it can be done by using html tags but how it can be done. Can you please any sample code for this. 
Thanks-

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761423/example-or-tutorial-of-sending-an-email-in-iphone-from-another-application

Answer (score 3):

**To send attachments:** You can use `MFMailComposeViewController` to send attachments from your app.

**1.** Add `MessageUI` framework, and do `#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>`

**2.** In your email button action or however you are sending email, add :

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) //IMPORTANT: check if mail can be sent to avoid crash
{
    MFMailComposeViewController*mailController=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    NSURL*yourUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourFilePath];
    NSData*attachData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourUrl];

    mailController.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [mailController addAttachmentData:attachData mimeType:@"yourExtension" fileName:@"yourFileName.yourExtension"];
    [mailController setSubject:@"Test Subject"];
    [mailController setTitle:@"Test Title"];


    if(mailController!=nil)
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
    }

    [mailController release];
}

else //give a prompt showing no mail accounts found
{
    UIAlertView*emailAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Email Account Found." message:@"Please set an email account." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [emailAlert show];
    [emailAlert release];
}
```

**To set signature**: I guess it uses the signature relative to the mail account that has been set. Sorry no idea on how to change it programmatically.